# Is there any equivalent of ADF copy activity in databricks?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I want to copy data into databricks from different external sources such as azure data lake, blob store, SQL databases, NOSQL databases etc.
Is there any way we can do this databricks just like we do using Azure Data Factory copy activity?

Comment: can you please confirm on source to target as databricks is not storage mechanism  and databricks is computing only

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) and Azure Databricks are both cloud-based data integration and processing services offered by Microsoft, but they serve different purposes and have different capabilities. ADF is primarily focused on data integration and movement, while Databricks is focused on data processing and analytics.

Databricks does have similar capabilities to ADF Copy activity to copy data, but it is implemented differently. In Databricks, you can use the Databricks [Delta Lake](https://Databricks%20does%20have%20similar%20capabilities%20to%20ADF%20Copy%20activity%20to%20copy%20data,%20but%20it%20is%20implemented%20differently.%20In%20Databricks,%20you%20can%20use%20the%20Databricks%20Delta%20Lake%20feature%20to%20read%20and%20write%20data%20from%20various%20external%20sources,%20including%20Azure%20Data%20Lake,%20Blob%20Store,%20SQL%20databases,%20NoSQL%20databases,%20and%20more.%20You%20can%20also%20use%20the%20Databricks%20File%20System%20(DBFS)%20to%20read%20and%20write%20data%20from%20various%20external%20sources.%20%20Databricks%20also%20provides%20various%20APIs%20and%20libraries%20that%20allow%20you%20to%20read%20and%20write%20data%20from%20various%20external%20sources%20using%20programming%20languages%20such%20as%20Python,%20R,%20and%20Scala.%20For%20example,%20you%20can%20use%20the%20PySpark%20library%20in%20Databricks%20to%20read%20and%20write%20data%20from%20various%20external%20sources%20using%20Python.) feature to read and write data from various external sources, including Azure Data Lake, Blob Store, SQL databases, NoSQL databases, and more. You can also use the Databricks File System (DBFS) to read and write data from various external sources.

Databricks also provides various APIs and libraries that allow you to read and write data from various [external sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/) using programming languages such as Python, Scala, etc.

Additional reference:

1. [Connect to data sources from Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/scenarios/databricks-connect-to-data-sources)
2. [Converting and ingesting data to Delta Lake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/#converting-and-ingesting-data-to-delta-lake)